# How to round decimal values for specific rule

Tags: decimal, rounding

I want to use a rule in excel for specific values. 
If price>=8.40 then price should be 8.99 and if price<8.40 then price is 7.99. Meaning if decimal value is >=40 then it should be .99 with same starting digit but if decimal value is <.40 then it should be starting value -1 and then .99. Sorry if i am unable to explain my requirement. Some examples are given below.

```
Present price       New Price
8.40                8.99
8.39                7.99
8.41                8.99
8.25                7.99
```

Comment: You use these things called "computer programs" for this sort of thing.

Comment: Just use an IF function for the values. Refer to http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx

Comment: Thanks but i require solution of decimal values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

`=ROUND(A1+0.1,0)-0.01`

Suppose the **Present Price** values reside in 'A' column, add the worksheet formula shown above in **New Price** Columns' first cell (e.g. B1) and expand it to the end of populated range.

*Note: regular Excel Round() to Integer worksheet Function typically uses value of **0.5** as a threshold for rounding up (otherwise it will round down to the nearest Integer). So, just increasing the value by 0.1 should suffice your task).*

Hope this will help. Rgds,